# Using Bundleconfig in html

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Can we use the following bundles in HTML Page instead of CSHTML. Bundle config will work in HTML or not?

```
@Scripts.Render("~/js")
```

Also, can we load JS files as per loading page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in a regular HTML page, because regular HTML will not be passed through the Razor processing engine, and the `@Scripts.Render()` is a C# method invoked using ASP.NET's Razor syntax (the `@` tells the Razor engine to interpret the next snippet as code instead of markup).

If you do this it'll probably just literally output the text @Scripts.Render("~/js") onto the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ADyson. Is there any other way to bundle files..? I'm using angular, HTML and asp.net.

Comment: what's the problem with using CSHTML page? You can still use Angular with it.

Comment: Yes. I'm changing into CSHTML now..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the bundle via JavaScript dynamically on demand, following code might help you.

```
<script>
        (function (w, d) {
            this.load = function (p, c) {
                if (typeof p == 'string' && (p = [].push(p)), Object.prototype.toString.call(p) === '[object Array]') {
                    for (var i in p) {
                        var s = d.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.src = p[i]; s.async = false;
                        var h = d.getElementsByTagName('head'); if (h[0]) { h[0].appendChild(s); }
                    } c && (s.onreadystagechange = c, s.onload = c);
                }
            }
            return this;
        }(window, document));


        var appjs='@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/scripts/app")';
        load('s', ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js'], function () {
            load('s', [appjs']);
        });
    </script>
```